# What is the actual path in C++ and how do I get the relative path?

Tags: c++, path, relative-path

Hey guys I am starting to learn C++, and there is one thing I do not understand - what is my actual path?

So, for example, in Python, the actual path of `xyz.py` is where I run `python3 xyz.py`. But, how does it work in C++?

My C++ project looks like this:

```
--build
--data
  --exampleData
--src
  --example1
    --include
    --src
      -FileToRun.cc
```

I build my project "example1" to the `build` directory. In my project, I want to open the `exampleData`, what is the relative path for it? Is it relative to the position of `FileToRun.cc`? Or is it dependentt on how I execute it, like in Python? Or something else?

Comment: Hi, Emilio7773, it'd be easier to answer your question if you provide a bit more details like on which OS & IDE tools you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relative path is relative to the calling process's current working directory, wherever that happens to be pointing at the moment it is used. The working directory can be specified by a parent process. Or change dynamically during the current process's lifetime.  So you can't really rely on the working directory being where you expect at any given moment.

Your C++ app's default working directory *may* be your `build` folder, depending on your configuration, but it will certainly not be your `src` folder, unless you explicitly set it up that way (for instance, by opening a terminal to the `src` folder and then running the executable without changing folders.  Or creating a shortcut to the executable and setting the working directory in the shortcut's properties).

This works the same in Python and C++, and any other language, as it is a feature of the OS, not the app.

If you want to ensure that your relative paths are relative to your executable (or any other root), then you should convert them to absolute paths at runtime.  Retrieve your executable's absolute folder path (such as with `GetModuleFileName()` on Windows, or `argv[0]` in `main()`, etc, then strip off the executable's filename), or whatever absolute root you want. Then append your relative path. And then resolve any remaining `.`/`..` as needed.

So, for example, if you have `<path>/build/example1.exe` and want to access `<path>/data/exampleData`, then you would

- start with `<path>/build/example1.exe`
- strip off the filename to get `<path>/build/`
- append `../data/exampleData` to get `<path>/build/../data/exampleData`
- resolve `/build/../data/` to `/data/`
- thus leaving you with `<path>/data/exampleData`

There are APIs to help with this task.  Such as `PathRemoveFileSpec()` and `PathCombine()`/`PathAppend()`/`PathCanonicalize()` on Windows.  Or the [`<filesystem>` library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) in C++17.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking what would be the `current working directory`(a.k.a. CWD) while running your executable and from there how to access your data located in a certain directory.

It depends on how you run the executable.

1. If you run it from terminal, it's likely that the current directory where you ran the executable would be the CWD. In this case you should already know how to get a relative path.
2. If you run it via IDE(such as Visual Studio on Windows), it's likely that the `build` directory would be the CWD because VS tends to set the output directory as CWD. In this case, I recommend you to check the project setting because what I just said is totally customizable in IDE. If `build` is set as CWD in the setting, you can access your data via `../data/exampleData/<your file>`

Though you can set the CWD in IDE in the case of #2, you may find it tricky to locate the directory that contains data after releasing your executable. (i.e., you build it as release version to publish it) Because the relative path could change depending on where you run the executable due to what's described in #1. So what I would suggest you to resolve this issue is to set the directory where the executable is located as the CWD by explicitly making a call to a system function in your program, so that your executable is consistently able to find your assets no matter how you run it.

- On Windows, you can use `SetCurrentDirectory` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/changing-the-current-directory)).
- On Linux-ish system, you can use `chdir` ([link](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html))